# Listing subgroups of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, computational-algebra

I made a program to list all the subgroups of any group and I came up with satisfactory result for $\operatorname{Symmetric Group}[3]$ as

$\left\{\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}]\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\}\right\}$

It excludes the whole set itself though it can be added seperately. But in case of $SymmetricGroup[4]$ I am getting following

$\left\{\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}]\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2 \\
 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 3 \\
 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 4 \\
 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\},\left\{\text{Cycles}[\{\}],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right],\text{Cycles}\left[\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 4 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right]\right\}\right\}$

The matrix form shows double transposition. Can someone please check for me if I am getting appropriate results? I doubt I am!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the impression that you only list the *cyclic* subgroups.

For $S_3$, the full group $S_3$ ist missing as a subgroup (you are mentioning that in your question).

For $S_4$, several subgroups are missing. In total, there should be $30$ of them. $14$ of them are cyclic, which are exactly the ones you listed. To give you a concrete example, the famous Klein Four subgroup
$$\{\operatorname{id},(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$$
is not contained in your list.

Comment: are you aware of the algorithm used to calculate subgroups ?

Comment: In the case of $S_4$, it still can be done by hand if you know some group theoretic basics. In general, the computation of all subgroups is a hard problem.

Comment: http://www.math.colostate.edu/~hulpke/talks/columbustalk.pdf

actually I know that but I found this link and tried though I am not doing what is specified there...it's so brief that I could barely make out anything out of it.

Answer (score 3):

By using GAP, you can make them all so easier and visible.

```
  gap> LoadPackage("sonata");;
  gap> s4:=SymmetricGroup(IsPermGroup,4);;
  gap> g:=Subgroups(s4);; 
  gap> List([1..Size(g)],k->g[k]);
```

Comment: I guess you want `SymmetricGroup`, not `AlternatingGroup`

Comment: @azimut: Yes. That's right. I'll edit it ;-)

Comment: Actually, one liner `AllSubgroups(SymmetricGroup(4));` also suffices, but please see some important hints from [http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7](http://www.gap-system.org/Faq/faq.html#7.7) from the GAP F.A.Q.

Comment: Nice work, Babak!

Comment: $\Large\color{blue}{+➀}\color{Violet}{⚛}\color{green}{✓}$@BabakS.